# Why the "default" keyword acts like "try + catch / orElse" in some cases

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I recently noticed an interesting behavior from the `default` keyword. It acts like `try-catch` or `try-orElse` in some situation.

For example, if you try to execute the following script:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
("ABC" as Number) default "Invalid number"
```

you will get the output as `Invalid number`!!. But if you remove the default part and only try `("ABC" as Number)` it will throw an error saying `Cannot coerce String (ABC) to Number`  which is expected.

Looks like the statement is behaving as it was

```js
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::Runtime
output application/json
---
try(() -> ("ABC" as Number)) orElse "Invalid number"
```

However, this is not the end of it. I cannot find this behavior documented but after some hits and trials I am seeing that it only works for the following errors:

1. Errors during type Coercion. Try `("ABC" as Number) default "default"`
2. Errors raised by using the function [`fail`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-runtime-functions-fail). Try `(dw::Runtime::fail("ERROR") default "default"`

There may be more but I am only able to get the info from hit and trials only as there is no documentation around this behavior that I can find.

I think the #1 is to make developers able to easily do something like

```js
payload.someField as Number default 0
```

without having them check for a `null` value **before** doing the coercion. I mean, otherwise, it would have failed at `payload.someField as Number` if the field is null, and this will be needed rewritten as

```js
(payload.someField default 0) as Number
```

My question is

1. Is this behavior reliable, and can I use this form `payload.someField as Number default 0` without worrying it will fail?
2. Is there a doc for this behavior of `default` keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story about the behavior of default is as you said it has two completely different capabilities.

1. is the one we all know is that it is when ever the left side is null return what ever is on the right.
2. It acts as an exception handler for some exceptions (this was inherited from dw 1 and sadly we can not change it)

What kind of exception are we handling?

1. Calling a function that doesn't support *null*
2. Any Coercion exception (like the one that you found)

*Is this behavior reliable, and can I use this form payload.someField as Number default 0 without worrying it will fail?*

To your answer your question, it is yes but not promoted. I would recommend using *try* for exception handling. But yes we are not going to change this behavior.

*Is there a doc for this behavior of default keyword?*

I don't see it in Anypoint documentation.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. So what you are saying is it supports some exception handling, but it is not a desired behavior, correct?

Comment: Can you also explain "Calling a function that doesn't support null". I tried this `daysBetween(null, now()) default ""` but I am getting error that the function expects date

Comment: @HarshankBansal To your first question, as in dw 1 there where no modules was the way we made it to support some odd cases like the multiple format cases. For your second question yes the type checker will not allow it but cases where the type checker doesn't realize that like the value is an Any for example

%dw 2.0
output application/json

var a: Any = null

fun test(a: String) = a
---
test(a) default "123"